# Sign In with Google/Facebook/Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, google-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating web application on which i am allowing user to sign in using Facebook/Google/Twitter.

Once user sign in i store their Respective ids from Facebook/Google/Twitter to database table.

Now i database table i am using same field something like **Social_ID** to store ids for all three(facebook/google/twitter).

Today i had thought that what if there is case of same/duplicate id from these providers.

So if anyone experienced in using all three for user sign in.

Could please share some info.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: No I guess there is very less probability to have a similar/duplicate id's

Comment: If you want to avoid any possible duplication, you can add prefix for ids from different providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO social_users (social_id, data)
                VALUES ('$social_id', '$data')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id";
```

the "social_id" field in your database must be unique.